# Use column that has a value within it - ignore blank columns

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have 3 columns where there will only ever be a value within one of the three columns. I'm trying to get that value into a single column to make the reporting easier.

Can anyone see where I'm going from with what I have below?

```
WhichForm = SWITCH (
    TRUE,
    ISBLANK([Column 1]) = FALSE, [Column 1],
    ISBLANK([Column 2]) = FALSE, [Column 2],
    ISBLANK([Column 3]) = FALSE, [Column 3]
)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be done in Power Query but if you want to use DAX, use the COALESCE() function.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/coalesce-function-dax